# needing/needed - what's the difference?

Tags: participles

> 1 We have some laptops needing to be fixed.
>
> 2 We have some laptops needed to be fixed.

I was told that **1** means that the laptops are still in need for a fix. **2** means that the need to fix them was in the past.

I construe that "needed" is a participle. What if we switch the sentences into the past?

> 3 We had some laptops needing to be fixed.
>
> 4 We had some laptops needed to be fixed.

3 means that at that time we had some laptops that needed to be fixed.

But what about 4? Is it correct? What does it mean?

Comment: 2 and 4 are not grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

'Needed' is the past participle of the verb *to need*, so it would not be appropriate to describe a laptop that is currently broken. You say that you *have* (present tense) these laptops, so the need to fix them is not in the past.

You could say "*we have some laptops **that** needed to be fixed*", meaning that in the past they needed to be fixed, but it is odd because if they no longer needed fixing surely you'd just say they *have been fixed*.

Using the present continuous "needing" carries the sense that the need is ongoing - that the laptops are 'waiting' to be fixed.

Comment: Do you claim that 2 doesn't make sense?

Comment: @user1425 Yes. As written, it is ungrammatical and illogical.

Comment: No. OP's example #2 is syntactically fine. It's just that it requires a *sightly* unusual context to make sense. *We have some laptops [that] needed to be fixed* implies ***we have fixed them** [so they don't need to be fixed **now**]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers example 2 is **not** syntactically fine. Read it again.

Comment: I don't understand. The second paragraph of your answer explicitly says #2 is okay. Unless you're saying the absence of ***that*** invalidates the construction, which isn't true.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No.

Comment: I believe there are some dialects where _that_ may be omitted even where the (omitted) relative is the subject of the relative clause; but not in standard Englishes. So "that" cannot be omitted.

Comment: I see, but why is this correct? I have a laptop needed by Jack.

Comment: @user1425 That's a kind of passive construction: Jack needs the laptop; the laptop *is* needed *by* Jack.  But in your sentence about fixing, the laptop is what does the needing, not someone else.